# How to utilize SwingWorker and/or Timer?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, timer, swingworker

I have been working on a program and am currently trying to resolve an issue. The program's purpose is to read through records from a database, pull information upon a certain trigger, and then display that information the GUI. The problem here is getting that data from the database to appear in the GUI, allow for some time for it to be represented on the screen, and then do the same for the next one and loop through.

I can get the data and put it on screen in the GUI, but my problem lies within allowing for that pause.

I have tried Thread.sleep but I have read that it is discouraged to do so.

What seems to be recommended is utilizing SwingWorker and/or Timer. I have spent a good amount of time studying these two but I am having difficulty fully understanding it and being able to apply it to my program. Given my problem and my program's purpose, can anyone help explain the significance of SwingWorker and Timer?

Answer (score 4):

Timer executes in the EDT and the SwingWorker makes work in another threads. I really like this example [Swing Worker example](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/)

> Note that the Swing timer's task is performed in the event dispatch
>   thread. This means that the task can safely manipulate components, but
>   it also means that the task should execute quickly. If the task might
>   take a while to execute, then consider using a SwingWorker instead of
>   or in addition to the timer.

Comment: Through my researcher on these topics I read a lot about the EDT and spent time looking into concurrency, however I am still confused about these concepts and its structure. I am a beginner programmer and the oracle docs didn't help me too much, could you recommend a better tutorial or lesson?

Thank-you for your contribution. *looks like you edited before I finished commenting, I'll look over your suggestion example

Comment: Heavy task use SwingWorker to don't block gui, Timer executes in `EDT`  and with repetitions with some delay between each one..

Comment: I am not sure if my task is heavy, in which case I would implement SwingWorker, or light, in which case I would just use the Timer. Is there an easy way to tell, or does it come with experience?

Comment: @Pat: yes you will know better with better with experience, but in general if the code takes more than a moment to process, do it in a background thread such as that provided by a SwingWorker. 1+ to the answer.

Comment: @Pat i think is try and error, but is better to know what options do you have and how to resolve, so if your task is quickly then make it in the `EDT` is not try to use `SwingWorker`

Answer (score 4):

### Caveats:

All interactions with the UI, updates, creates, should be done from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

### javax.swing.Timer

The Swing Timer is a special timer that allows you to setup a periodical callback that is guaranteed to execute within the context of the EDT

### SwingWorker

`SwingWorker` is solution desinged to make a UI developers life easier by providing the mechanisms for running code in the background while providing easy (at least easier) mechanisms for synchronizing updates to the UI within the EDT.

For your problem, I would recommend the use of the `SwingWorker`, as you can pause in the background without effecting the UI's responsiveness

```
SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<Object, Object> {

    public void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        while (!loadingDone) {
            Object data = loadMoreData();
            publish(data);
        }
        // This only matter if you actually care about the result
        // of what has being processed here...
        return null;
    }

    public void process(List<Object> chunks) {
         // Now in the UI...
    }

}
```

Check out...

- [`SwingWorker` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)
- [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

For more details...

Comment: better answer :) more complete +1

Comment: @nachokk A "longer" answer indeed, but your points are still valid (also +1 to you)